# Testing Draper-enhanced models using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, draper

I have an rspec test for my view which worked fine before I abstracted out some of the logic using draper. The view renders correctly in the browser, but the test now fails.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "articles/index.html.erb" do
  before(:each) do
    assign(:articles, [
      stub_model(Article,
        :title => "Title",
        :slug => "this-is-a-slug",
        :content => "Content",
        :excerpt => "Excerpt",
        :starts_at => "2012-01-10 01:00:00",
        :ends_at => "2012-01-10 01:30:00",
        :show_times => true
      )
    ])
    render
  end

  it "renders a list of articles" do
    assert_select "h3", :text => "Title".to_s, :count => 8
    assert_select "div.article_body", :text => "Content".to_s, :count => 8
  end
end
```

The view contains a call to the decorator method `calendars`, which is defined in decorators/article_decorator.rb, but rspec is not picking this up, presumably because I'm using stub_model:

```
1) articles/index.html.erb renders a list of articles
   Failure/Error: render
   ActionView::Template::Error
   undefined method `calendars' for #<Article:0x007fd41c68be90>
   # ./app/views/articles/index.html.erb:4:in `block in _app_views_articles_index_html_erb___1865228919968458103_70274492660680'
   # ./app/views/articles/index.html.erb:1:in `each'
   # ./app/views/articles/index.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_articles_index_html_erb___1865228919968458103_70274492660680'
   # ./spec/views/articles/index.html.erb_spec.rb:85:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How can I make my tests work again? (Or is there a better way of testing my views?)

Answer (score 1):

I have not started to use Draper yet, but i guess this should work:

```
assign(:articles, [
    ArticleDecorator.new(
      stub_model(Article,
        :title => "Title",
        :slug => "this-is-a-slug",
        :content => "Content",
        :excerpt => "Excerpt",
        :starts_at => "2012-01-10 01:00:00",
        :ends_at => "2012-01-10 01:30:00",
        :show_times => true
        )
      )])
```

Now articles is an Array of Decorators, who respond to `calendars` method.